# Поля Галуа GF(2^8)

Tags: полином, шифрование

В чем ошибка при умножении в поле Галуа `GF(2^8)`.
Пример: `57*83=x^7+x^6+1`.

```
57 из HEX в BIN (1010111)  
83 из HEX в BIN (10000011)
```

Соответственно представим, как:

```
(1+x+x2+x4+x6)(1+x+x7)
```

т.к у `57` на позициях `x3` и `x5` стоят нули, то мы их не записываем, по тому же принципу записали `83`.

```
(x6+x4+x2+x+1)(x7+x+1)=x13+x11+x9+x8+/x7/+/x7/+x5+x3+/x2/+/x/+x6+x4+/x2/+/x/+1 = 
x13+x11+x9+x8+x5+x3+x6+x4+1
```

(Т.к. в ответе есть одинаковые значения, то мы избавимся от них, помечены /)

Теперь посчитаем:

```
x13+x11+x9+x8+x6+x5+x4+x3+1 mod (x8+x4+x3+x+1)
```

где `x8+x4+x3+x+1` - это предельное значение в Поле Галуа по `2^8`, которое мы не можем превысить.

Запишем все в BIN:

```
10101101111001 mod (100011011)
```

То есть

```
11129 mod 283 = 92
```

Правильный ответ: `x7+x6+1`, то есть   `11000001 = 193`.

У меня получилось `92`.

Объясните, в чем моя ошибка, может быть, деление `mod` происходит совсем иначе?

Answer (score 1):

Хм, я удивился что за месяц никто не ответил. Да, ты был прав, деление идет в полях Галуа не совсем так как обычное. Если делить так же в столбик, то нужно вместо вычитания каждый раз использовать операцию xor ( если одинаковые то нолик, если разные то единица ). Пример как решить на картинке. И если еще будут вопросы по полям Галуа спрашивай, я их неплохо знаю.[image: пример решения.]